# Vuetify Combobox Not Returning id instead of value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a form full of `<v-combobox>` that basically autocompletes for the person filling in the form.  I've succeeded at doing just that, but I'm having a weird issue.  When I actually select an item that the `<v-combobox>` suggests it fills in the input correctly.  However, when it submits the form it sends the `id` in the options array rather than the value that I selected.  These seems wrong to me because I set the `item-value="key"` to the same as `item-text="key"` and the text is correct as the string I want, so why isn't the value?

```js
<v-flex
  v-for="key in inputsNames"
  v-if="key !== 'id'"
  :key="key"
  xs12
>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="editForm[key]"
    :item-text="key"
    :label="key"
    :loading="loading"
    :search-input.sync="inputSearch[key]"
    :items="searchOptions"
    :item-value="key"
    cache-items
    clearable
    prepend-icon="filter_list"
  />
</v-flex>
```

For example:
Filling the `x, y` fields with the autocomplete and the others manually will return the following error message:

**Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `table` (`w`, `x`, `y`, `z`) values (test, 5, 4, 1)) **

In this case `5, 4,` should've been two strings.

UPDATE:

Still not solved but I've found that its actually sending the whole item object to the POST.

Comment: could you provide the script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2019:**
I've looked into this issue again and found the answer finally.  It's related to the `return-object` property which is apparently true by default.  Disabling it causes the `v-combobox` to work as expected.

```
<v-combobox
    :item-text="(obj) => (obj)[key]"
    :item-value="(obj) => (obj)[key]"
    v-model="editForm[key]"
    :search-input.sync="editForm[key]"
    :items="searchOptions"
    :return-object="false"
>
```

**Original Solution:**
For people with a similarly complex use of the combobox in the future, I've solved this one.  Weirdly the standard `:item-value` prop does not work with a multi-combobox setup as I've done here.  I can't explain why.  The solution I've found is to provide a custom mapping to the key for the `:items` prop like this:

```
<v-flex
    v-for="key in columns"
    v-if="key !== 'id'"
    :key="key"
    xs12
>
    <v-combobox
        :item-text="key"
        v-model="editForm[key]"
        :search-input.sync="inputSearch[key]"
        :items="searchOptions.map((obj) => (obj)[key])"
    />
</v-flex>
```

This will allow you to generate many comboboxes and use the same script to fetch for all of them while still having them function independently as intended.

Comment: Using `:return-object="false"` does trigger the behavior that the "item-id" value is shown instead of the "item-name"; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482761/vuetify-combobox-displaying-the-id-instead-of-the-item-text

Comment: This is without a doubt the most awful component in the entire vuetify eco system. It's just awful. Just doesn't work as expected AT ALL.

Answer (score 2):

For Vue 3.0 we have a small change:
item-title instead item-text

```
<v-combobox
  :items="[{ key: 'john', value: '1' }, { key: 'Marie', value: '2' }]"
  item-title="key"
  item-value="value"
  label="ComboBox"
/>
```