# Vuetify combobox displaying the id instead of the item-text

Tags: combobox, vuetify.js

I have the following combobox in Vuetify:

```
<v-combobox v-model="supplier.supplier_type" maxlength="255" :items="company.supplier_types" item-text="name" item-value="id" :label="$t('supplier.supplier_types')" :hide-no-data="true" outlined :error-messages="errors" :return-object="false">
</v-combobox>
```

However, although the item-text is being displayed correctly in the item slot, it displays the id instead in the selection slot:

[image]

Am I suppoused to change anything on the combobox?

I tried specificying the item-text by using the slot, but that didn't work out:

```
<v-combobox v-model="supplier.supplier_type" maxlength="255" :items="company.supplier_types" item-text="name" item-value="id" :label="$t('supplier.supplier_types')" :hide-no-data="true" outlined :error-messages="errors" :return-object="false">
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        {{item.name}}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{ on, item }">
        <v-list-item v-on="on">
            {{item.name}}
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently [a bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5479) regarding `item-value`, if `return-object` is set to false.

Quote from the Report: "When the return-object prop is set to false on a v-combobox, the text-field 'item-text' apparently gets changed to the id of the item-value."

It is mentioned in the [documentation of `v-combobox`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#props-item-value).

Removing `item-value="id"` should fix it, but results in the whole object being the value.

Comment: I've literally given up using it. Shockingly bad component that seems utterly broken, even now in 2023 ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Max, there's an issue with this component.

I'm unsure if v-select would fit your scenario, so maybe you could try it.

On [v-select](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/), you can use an array of strings or objects. The only detail is that the objects should follow contain [structure](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props).

In my case, I just created a computed prop that returns the expected structure.

```
computed: {
    vSelectStatus() {
      return this.statusList.map((status) => ({ value: status.id, text: status.name }))
    }
}
```

And my template uses it as:

```
<template>
   <v-select label="Status" :items="vSelectStatus" v-model="user.status" />
</template>
```